# Prevent new session when opening picture file with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, session, screen-resolution, visitor-statistic

Opening a picture file with php is done in a new session, How can I prevent this behaviour?

I have put a javascript in all of my web pages to get screen resolution. Here is the javascript code:

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
 document.getElementById("mypictureid").src="http://www.mywebsite.com/getresolutionpic.php?w="+screen.width+"&h="+screen.height;
</script>
```

and the html of the pages includes:

```
<img id="mypictureid" src="http://mywebsite.com/otherimage.gif"
```

and the following php code will be executed with each page loading to store user data in $_SESSION.

```
$some_name = session_name("generalvisit");
session_start();
$_SESSION['entertime']=new DateTime();
```

and to track the user a userid is created by a mysql database and stores in $_SESSION['userid']

```
if(!is_numeric($_SESSION['userid']) $_SESSION['userid']=getNewUserID();
```

now, when the  `getresolutionpic.php` is triggered by javascript,  store screen resolution of that user stores in the `$_SESSION` variable of the same user. In `getresolutionpic.php` we have:

```
$some_name = session_name("generalvisit");
session_start();
if(!is_numeric($_SESSION['userid'])
{
    $_SESSION['userid']=getNewUserID();
    $_SESSION['entertime']=new DateTime();
}
$_SESSION['width']=$_GET['w'];
$_SESSION['height']=$_GET['h'];
```

The problem is that when getresolutionpic.php is called, `$_SESSION['userid']` is empty and a new userid will be created while the user is not actually new.

Do you have any idea where it goes wrong?

Comment: It's not exactly the same question, but see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481493/php-session-class/24481522#24481522 The cause is the same.

Comment: If you create the session in the script that returns the original HTML and JS, I think it should work.

Comment: @Barmar. the session is created in a file that is included in html file, should I change this?

Comment: No, that's fine. My question was whether you're creating it when the original page is loaded, or only in the image scripts.

Comment: @Barmar, Thanks, I think my problem is the same as the mentioned question. now, How can I prevent loading image script until the main html file is fully loaded ?(to prevent doubling session)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my mistake that caused this problem was that some where I had used http://mywebsite.com/etc.. instead of http://www.mywebsite.com/etc.. so the `$_SESSION` variable created in the former was unavailable in the later pages.

But I solved the problem by some changes in the way codes executes. Now, I read the `w` and `h` inputs in all the pages in the domain, not just in `getresolutionpic.php` script. and I treat  `getresolutionpic.php` just like any other php file in the site. in fact, `getresolutionpic.php` will do nothing more than reading image file and sending it to the user.

hope I have been clear enough to be helpful for people who face the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("mypictureid").src = "http://www.mywebsite.com/getresolutionpic.php?w=" + screen.width + "&h="+screen.height;
</script>
```

This doesn't try to load the image until the main page is loaded, and the session cookie should be set at that time.