# jquery ajax post in session

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem with jquery ajax's post method.

What trying to doing , When user upload multiple file on sucess upload it to session and save to database , but if im using alert it's correctly working ,

```
 $('#uploader_div').ajaxupload({
                                    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>product/multifile',
                                    editFilename: true,
                                    form: '#create',
                                    //autoStart: true,
                                    remotePath: 'product/<?php echo $id; ?>',
                                    thumbHeight: 300,
                                    finish: function(files_array) {
                                        $.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>product/file_upload", {files: files_array});
                                        //alert ("Workin");


                                    },
                                    //max number of files can be selected

                                });
```

Im working on Real ajax uploder in codeigniter

Here is my other part of code

```
public function multifile() {
    $this->load->helper('upload_helper');
}

public function file_upload() {
    $data = array();
    $id = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $files = $this->input->post('files', true);


    $i = 1;
    foreach ($files as $files) {
        $images = "img_" . $i;
        $data [$images] = base_url() . "product/" . $id . "/". $files;
       $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        $i++;
    }
}
```

In view :  $this->session->unset_userdata('img_1');
flow of function upload->set session->data save to db -> onsucess removed from session 
But if i removed the alert the image not comes up it set 0 value , actually my $.post images array not working hope understandable now !

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, but I think it's the same as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481493/php-session-class/24481522#24481522

Comment: Hey Barmar , Thanks for your comment , I have Edit this question hope this will get help from Expert code ...

Comment: Make sure you start the session when you create the initial page. Then it will be available when all the AJAX calls take place.

Comment: Thanks , but i have already session start with usr login ...

Comment: Then I'm not sure why you're having a problem. Maybe it's something specific to codeigniter, I don't know anything about that.

Comment: Thanks Barmar , Im also stuck this stage , But Helpless , If anyone know i'm also try to find out why not working without alert ..